# mongoose findbyId() showing 'The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of model'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

so this is my code here (express)

```
    app.get('/:id', async (req,res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        console.log(id)
        const bids = await Bid.findById(id)
        res.render(bids)
    
    })
```

so this is what I got in the console

```
61671cef1c1db40b750502b0
(node:8068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of model
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
    at extname (path.js:828:5)
    at new View (D:\konectapp-1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:56:14)
    at Function.render (D:\konectapp-1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\konectapp-1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at D:\konectapp-1\app.js:62:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8068) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I can see it is providing the object id at the top of the console as I have logged, but when I passed it to the findbyid , it is giving me this error

Answer (score 2):

> ...but when I passed it to the findbyid , it is giving me this error

There seems to be nothing wrong with the mongoose `findById()`, although it's better to handle the errors properly when using `async/await` with a `try/catch` block.

> [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string...

This throws from `res.render(bids)`.

`res.render()` only accepts a string which is the file path of the view file to render. But here you're passing an object as the parameter. [See the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render).

Comment: To add to this, I suspect that what they really want to do is send a JSON representation of the bids object. You can do this via `res.json(bids)` instead of using a template.